# R script email library

Tags: r, rscript

Hi I'm using R script to update data and I've added it as a CRON job. Is there any library available in R that would send an email? I want to be able to send out an email if an exception occurs.

Comment: Try the sendmailR package.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck it works well with smtp just not exchange server.

Comment: Exchange supports SMTP connections, but it is most likely locked down to certain hosts in your environment. It is easy to enable it on a system-by-system basis. Just ask your admins.